# SAIKU UI SHARE GLOBAL VARIABLE BETWEEN VIEWS

Tags: javascript, user-interface, variables, global, saiku

I am working on a project that runs queries based on some filters. I want the users to be able to view their selected values when hovering over a particular filter in the filterView. The options are selected from a pop up selectOptions view. How do I share a variable that contains the selected options between the two views once the selectOptions pop up view has been closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden input to keep your data for the next step

Comment: Won't that hidden input be tied to a view? How will I acces it from the other view?